# .xcworkspace does not generate via firebase unity SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, admob, cocoapods

I'm a beginner for unity. I use Firebase unity SDK 3.0.1 and GoogleMobileAdsPlugin 3.2.

My unity is 5.4.1.

I export IOS project according to the tutorial in https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup. But I can't find a .xcworkspace  file.

It generates a default Podfile file.

```
source 'htps://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'   
install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => false
platform :ios, '7.0'
target 'Unity-iPhone' do  
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '3.14.0'  
pod 'Firebase/Core', '3.14.0'  
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.13'  
end
```

After pod install,.xcworkspace  appear if I delete `"install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => false"`.

I want to know whether the .xcworkspace file is necessary or not when I use Firebase unity SDK?

Because other firebase tutorials tell me .xcworkspace is necessary like https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/games?hl=zh-cn#_3.

If it is necessary, what I should do to generate it or a correct Podfile?

Answer (score 0):

The Podfile is correct, but `:integrate_targets => false` skips generating an xcworkspace.

As you noticed, removing that line from the Podfile makes cocoapods generate the desired workspace and also integrates the pods in it.

So removing the line is ok.

Comment: Thank you for reply.Because this is the default generated file.I am not confident when I remove it.   I think that is that now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had project with same folder name("Project") ending with 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 (total 5 folders). when i was trying to install cocoapods in "Project 4" directory it was getting installed in "Project" instead it should be for "Project 4".

Hence i need to delete other folders with same name and then install pods in "Project" folder.